# How can be solved this organization web app problem?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I need some help. I am developing a mineral selling-buying online app and currently i need some help. The nav bar has 4 sections. The main menu called mineral world, the buying section, the selling section and the last one give people more information about minerals. I need to divide my mineral list ( from json file) in the two sections. Those that have the buysell parameter 1 will be put in the buy section and those that have the buysell parameter 2 will be put in the sell section and the minerals will not be displayed in the main section and in the more information section. Has anyone any idea how can I do this operation ? The code is down bellow. Thank you in advance.

#mineral-world.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IMineral } from '../Mineral/IMineral.interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MineralWorldService {




  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
   }
    getAllMinerals(BuySell: number): Observable<IMineral[]>
    {
     return this.http.get('data/minerals.json').pipe( map((data:any)=>
      {
           const mineralsArray: Array<IMineral> =[];
             for (const id in data){
             if(data.hasOwnProperty(id) && data[id].BuySell === BuySell)
             {
               mineralsArray.push(data[id]);
             }
            }
           return mineralsArray;
      }
          )
    );
    }
}
```

#nav-bar.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark link bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">Mineral-World</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" style="margin-right: 400px;">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " aria-current="page" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/buy-minerals">Buy</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" routerLinkActive="active"  routerLink="/sell-minerals">Sell</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" routerLinkActive="active"  routerLink="/information-about-minerals">Information about Minerals</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" >
        <input class="form-control me-2"type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

#mieral-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MineralWorldService } from 'src/app/services/mineral-world.service';
import { IMineral } from '../IMineral.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mineral-list',
  templateUrl: './mineral-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mineral-list.component.css']
})
export class MineralListComponent implements OnInit {

  BuySell= 1;
  minerals!: Array<IMineral>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private mineralworldService: MineralWorldService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void
  {
      if ( this.route.snapshot.url.toString())
      {
        this.BuySell = 2;
      }


    this.mineralworldService.getAllMinerals(this.BuySell).subscribe(
      (       data: any)=>{
        this.minerals=data;
        console.log(data);
      }, error =>{
        console.log('httperror:');
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

#mineral.json

```
[
  {
      "id":1,
      "BuySell":1,
      "Name":"Gold 22k",
      "Formula":"Au",
      "Price":"100",
      "Quantity":"20",
      "Image":"gold22k"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "BuySell":2,
    "Name":"Pink Quartz",
    "Formula":"SiO2",
    "Price":"80",
    "Quantity":"20",
    "Image":"pink-quartz"
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "BuySell":1,
    "Name":"Tiger Eyes",
    "Formula":"SiO2",
    "Price":"200",
    "Quantity":"10",
    "Image":"tiger-eyes"
  },
  {
    "id":4,
    "BuySell":2,
    "Name":"Amethiyst",
    "Formula":"SiO2 Fe+3",
    "Price":"150",
    "Quantity":"15",
    "Image":"amethiyst"
  },
  {
    "id":5,
    "BuySell":1,
    "Name":"Pyrites",
    "Formula":"FeS2",
    "Price":"50",
    "Quantity":"30",
    "Image":"pyrites"
  },
  {
    "id":6,
    "BuySell":1,
    "Name":"mineral",
    "Formula":"-",
    "Price":"-",
    "Quantity":"-",
    "Image":"mineral-gen"
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: i run this code and i doesn't work how i want. In the main section, it appears the minerals that should be bought, in the buy section appears the minerals that should be sold, in the sell section nothing appears and in the last section appears just like in the buy section. I want that in the buy section to appear the minerals that can be bought, and now those are in the main section, and in the sell section i want to appear the minerals that can be sold and now those are in the buy and in the more information section. This is my problem. Is there any way to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the reduce it'll be simple:

```
 getAllMinerals(buySell: number): Observable<IMineral[]> {
    return this.http.get('data/minerals.json').pipe(map((data: any) => {
      return data.reduce((allMinerals: IMineral[], currentMineral: IMineral) => {
        currentMineral.BuySell === buySell ?
          allMinerals.push(currentMineral) :
          allMinerals
        return allMinerals
      }, [])
    }));
  }
```

I recommend write the first letter in the parameters in `lower case`.

Comment: I added the new code that you wrote above. There aren't any modifications in the app. Would i need to make any other modifications in the other file to obtain something like i said in the comment above ?